# Macbook Pro 14 Won't Boot

Tags: startup

I have a 2017 Macbook Pro 14 (model A1708). Whenever I attempt to boot, the screen turns on, and nothing else happens.

I can access the Apple boot menu, but I got the same result when I tried booting an external drive (macOS Monterey installer, Manjaro Linux installation ISO, Alpine Linux live ISO). I have secure boot disabled, successfully booted the Manjaro iso a year ago, and haven't changed anything other than manually setting one of the ports (sdb) as bootable via efibootmgr in Manjaro the day before the computer stopped booting.

Oddly enough, none of the other key combinations do anything, as far as I can tell.

Is my computer bricked?

Comment: Did you try [resetting the NVRAM or SMC on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)?

Comment: Yes; the outcome was the same